# passport.js + express + apollo-server, req.user is undefined

Tags: express, graphql, passport.js, apollo-server

I tried to record sessions in the database through sequelize, to make it serverless, but `req.user` is always undefined, I tried every manual which I found on the internet, I do not understand why it not working.

I tried passport.js manual, express manuals, github gists.

Records in the database are successfully created, on successful authentication, but when I try hit `/graphql` endpoint, it does not fill `req.user` with user.

`req.user` should be restored based on session hash which is stored in database.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { typeDefs, resolvers } from './graphql';
import orm from './orm';
import compose from './dataloader/status.dataloader';
import passport from 'passport';
import { Strategy as GitHubStrategy } from 'passport-github';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: ({ req }) => {
        const user = req.user;
        console.log({ user });
        return {
            user,
            orm,
            dataloader: compose(orm),
        };
    },
});

passport.use(
    new GitHubStrategy(
        {
            clientID: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackURL: `/auth/github/callback`,
        },
        async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
            const { provider, id: externalId, profileUrl, username, displayName, photos } = profile;
            const photo = photos && photos[0] && photos[0].value;

            const user = await orm.User.findOne({
                include: [
                    {
                        attributes: [],
                        model: orm.UserProvider,
                        where: {
                            provider,
                            externalId,
                        },
                    },
                ],
                raw: true,
            }).then(async (v) => {
                if (null !== v) {
                    return v;
                }

                v = await orm.User.create({
                    displayName,
                    photo,
                });

                await orm.UserProvider.create({
                    provider,
                    internalId: v.id,
                    externalId,
                    username,
                    profileUrl,
                });

                return v;
            })

            const session = await orm.UserSession.create({
                internalId: user.id,
                hash: accessToken,
            });

            return done(null, session);
        }
    )
);

passport.serializeUser(({ hash }, done) => {
    console.log({ hash });
    done(null, hash);
});
passport.deserializeUser(async (hash, done) => {
    console.log({ hash });
    const user = await orm.User.findOne({
        include: [
            {
                attributes: [],
                model: orm.UserSession,
                where: {
                    hash,
                },
            },
        ],
        raw: true,
    });

    done(null, user);
});

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: "*",
        methods: "GET,POST",
        preflightContinue: false,
        optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
        credentials: true,
    })
);

app.use(session({ secret: 'test' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get(
    '/auth/github',
    passport.authenticate('github', { session: true })
);
app.get(
    '/auth/github/callback',
    passport.authenticate('github', { session: true }),
    (req, res) => res.redirect('/')
);
app.use('/graphql', passport.authenticate('session', { session: true }));
// (req, res, next) => {
//     debugger;
//     // passport.
//     console.log({
//         req,
//         session: JSON.stringify(req.session, ',', 4),
//         cookie: JSON.stringify(req.cookie),
//         user: req.user,
//     });

//     return next();
// });

server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' });
app
    .listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
        console.log(`GraphQL ready on: http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}/graphql`);
    });
```

Comment: How are you hitting your `/graphql` endpoint?

Comment: @Jim, via browser as GET, as well as I expect cookie to be persisted, so i can be reached via POST

Comment: Is `user` a cookie?  In which case, I believe `cookies` is inside your `req` object

Comment: `app.use(session({ secret: 'test' }));`
`app.use(passport.initialize());`
`app.use(passport.session());`

according documentation is enough, I debugged more

it seems passport make user:

`{ url: 'http://localhost:8081/graphql',`
`  user: `
`   { id: 2,`
`     displayName: 'xxx'.`
`     photo: 'xxx },`
`  session:`
`   Session {`
`     cookie:`
`      { path: '/',`
`        _expires: null,`
`        originalMaxAge: null,`
`        httpOnly: true },`
`     passport: { user: 'xxx' } },`
`  cookie: undefined }`

but after 2nd reload, it disappear for some reason

Comment: i was debugging this issue, I think i nail it down to the problem level: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/3178